# Wix install patches (for all users) without admin rights, given that the certificate is the same

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

The objective is basically to install the app for the first time (using admin privileges, for all users), but thereafter let non-admins update/upgrade it (for all users), given that the new installers are signed with the same certificate as the original installer.

It can be a patch or a whole new installer. Either way, is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The concept is called UAC Patching (or LUA Patching in the verbose log), and is documented in detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372388.aspx). The crux of it is a matching certificate that is both stored in the [MsiPatchCertificate table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370342.aspx), and used to sign the patch.

There are a lot of caveats, including certificate expiration, that you have to account for if avoiding subsequent UAC prompts is critical. See the [PatchCertificates element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/patchcertificates.html) for ensuring the certificate is stored in the MsiPatchCertificate table.

Comment: Do you know how to add a new PatchCertificates element to the wxs file? Also, does this need to be added to the patch wxs as well? I can't find anything on this and all my patches still require admin permissions even if signed by the same certificate as the original installer.

Comment: It's hard to assess something of this complexity via comments. Consider updating your question (or asking another) to clarify which of the items on [User Account Control (UAC) Patching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372388.aspx) you have confirmed you have satisfied, and which are you having trouble confirming.

Comment: I followed this guide (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html) . Ok here's what I've done so far. Added `PatchCertificates` and `PackageCertificates` tags to my main wsx. After the MSI is built I sign it using the same certificate. After the patch is build I sign it using the same certificate as well. I run try to install the app, works as expected. I then try to install the patch. Unfortunately UAC pops up. If I accept it, the patch ends up installing perfectly. My problem is that the patch still requires admin rights.

Comment: I peek at the 2 installers using Orca and also during the UAC dialog and they are both signed with the valid certificate.

Comment: Please check this question out. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614931/wix-installing-patches-without-admin-rights