# Wix - installing patches without admin rights

Tags: wix

Following is the wxs file for the main installer. This will be signed with Sign.pfx after it is created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD"
        Name="WiX Patch Example Product"
        Language="1033"
        Version="1.0.0"
        Manufacturer="Dynamo Corporation"
        UpgradeCode="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD">
        <Package Description="Installs a file that will be patched."
            Comments="This Product does not install any executables"
            InstallerVersion="200"
            Compressed="yes" AdminImage="no" />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>


        <FeatureRef Id="SampleProductFeature"/>

        <PatchCertificates>
            <DigitalCertificate Id="MyNewCertificate" SourceFile="Sign.pfx"/>
        </PatchCertificates>

        <PackageCertificates>
            <DigitalCertificate Id="MyNewCertificate" SourceFile="Sign.pfx"/>
        </PackageCertificates>

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Feature Id="SampleProductFeature" Title="Sample Product Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="SampleComponent" />
        </Feature>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SampleProductFolder">
            <Component Id="SampleComponent" Guid="{C28843DA-EF08-41CC-BA75-D2B99D8A1983}" DiskId="1">
                <File Id="SampleFile" Name="Sample.txt" Source=".\$(var.Version)\Sample.txt" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
                <Directory Id="SampleProductFolder" Name="Patch Sample Directory">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Following is the patch file which needs to be installed without requiring admin rights.Currently the patch works fine but requires admin rights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch 
        AllowRemoval="yes"
        Manufacturer="Dynamo Corp" 
        MoreInfoURL="http://www.dynamocorp.com/"
        DisplayName="Sample Patch" 
        Description="Small Update Patch" 
        Classification="Update"
        >

        <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="RTM.cab">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM"/>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="SamplePatchFamily"/>

    </Patch>

    <Fragment>    
        <PatchFamily Id='SamplePatchFamily' Version='1.2.0.0' Supersede='yes' ProductCode="48C49ACE-90CF-4161-9C6E-9162115A54DD">
            <ComponentRef Id="SampleComponent"/>
        </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The example code was taken from the official wix tutorial at http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html

How can I make it so that the application is installed for all users (with admin rights) (currently done) but non-admins can install the patch file.

What I've tried: added the `PatchCertificates` and `PackageCertificates`. Makes no difference.

Comment: Are there any hints in a verbose log file created when installing the patch? Search for `LUA`.

Comment: LUA=0 in both the main installer and the patch. There's also an entry that says `LUA patching is disabled: missing MsiPatchCertificate table`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the examples I can find use a .cer file instead of a .pfx for a `PatchCertificates/DigitalCertificate/@SourceFile` (e.g. [Question about UAC patching on Vista-patch certificate is not recognized](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/252f577e-4d9c-4f4c-a102-bd0050f02e01/question-about-uac-patching-on-vistapatch-certificate-is-not-recognized?forum=windowscompatibility) which includes alternate directions for [creating a .cer from a .pfx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403174) if you don't have one already, leveraging `MsiGetFileSignatureInformation`.) It's possible you need to specify a .cer file instead.